# Ubuntu 18.04 PHP 7.3 - Apache connection without apt install

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apt

Due to some proxy limitations, I cannot use public repositories for installing applications, and the highest PHP version I could install is 7.2, while I needed to use 7.3.

I have followed installation as described here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/8820491113/

I had previously version 7.2 in here and although I have successfully installed v7.3:

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 17 2021 15:10:37) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.28, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

info.php still is relating to "Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /etc/php/7.2/apache2" also it is throwing errors while executing lines related to version 7.3. (*7.3 is installed: /usr/local/php/bin/php*)
I know that solution might be installing `libapache2-mod-php` for PHP 7.3 and later `sudo a2enmod php7.3` but I can only find 7.2 and 7.4 in packages.ubuntu.com and cannot use `apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3`, so I cannot get it, also `sudo a2enmod php7.3` says `ERROR: Module php7.3 does not exist!`

I have restarted Apache of course.

Any advice?:)

Comment: _“while I needed to use 7.3”_ - why that specific version, why can’t you just go with 7.4 then?

Comment: If you can’t get the proper Apache _module_ version of PHP installed, then you might need to switch to a different way of embedding PHP with the web server, like FastCGI.